# What is long-format in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, ls

What exactly is the *long format* in Linux?.
I am a newbie into programming and Linux. So I was taking a tutorial in terminal operations.
This command `ls -l` is said to list the files in the working directory in *long format*.
Can somebody explain or give resources explaining about the *long format* and its use?

Comment: Have you compared `ls -l` with `ls`?

Comment: Why don't you try `ls` with and without `-l` and check the difference ?

Comment: Better answers to this question can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already may know, `ls` shows you the directories and files in your current folder.

`ls -l` (or shortly ll) prints you the long format as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-xr root root 1093 Oct 7 09:26 file
```

these stand for:

- permissions(r-read,x-execute,w-write) if any of these fields is disabled, you don't have the permission to do it.
- `root root` stands for the owner of the file and the group owner (you will find out about root as you carry on learning about linux).
- Next is the file size, after which the date the file was created, the time when it was last modified and the files name.

For more explanation visit this link: http://go2linux.garron.me/command-ls-file-permissions

Comment: This isn't a great answer. You can't say 'if any of these fields is disabled, you don't have the permission to do it' if you don't know who the user is. Secondly, the timestamp shows you the *modification* date and time, not the creation date and modification time. (It would be quite absurd for a timestamp to mix these two things together!)

Comment: Link is broken, and info is incomplete (permissions are not just r,w or x which is what I was looking this up for) - the link @Kal gives in their comment on the question gives better information.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "long format" simply means a format that is longer than some other format. There is no general Linux or UNIX concept of "long format". In this case, it refers to the output format produced by the `ls` command with the `-l` option, and *only* to that.

The "long format" used by `ls` is documented in the `ls` document (`man ls` or `info ls`), and can be seen by comparing the output of `ls -l` to the output of `ls`.

Other commands may have their own long formats, either based on the `ls` long format or not.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for the downvote (after all these years).

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but as it happens I just came to this question a few hours after your comment and this is the only answer that properly addresses the question, so have a +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

You can try some command such as

```
ls
ls -c
ls -g
ls -i
```

then try

```
ls -l
```

For some command you will get column wise information of files/directories.

For command like `ls -l`, you will get the output in for each entry in detailed format.

Some options on `ls` work like `ls -l`, but we can reduce some information by invoking the commands like `ls -g`.